# Ubuntu after upgrade - ssh exchange failed

Tags: server, 16.04, ssh

I have a little bit problem after upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04.
I've try to estabilish SSH connections with some servers trough SSH but after upgrade in some cases I have these output:

```
Unable to negotiate with 10.13.45.221 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

I know about adding this : `ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@legacyhost`

But maybe is another way to enable it globally and use only ssh user@host like in 14.04?

Answer (score 5):

This means the `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` is not present in the default set of key exchange algorithms.

To get the `ssh` option permanent, add the follwoing to your `~/.ssh/config` (or globally in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`):

```
KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Be careful about the `Host`, `Match` etc selective declarations while adding the directive if you want it globally as values inside those snippets apply to the mentioned set only. Whenever unsure, put it at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys this is what it worked for me

Adding this line above to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

Uncomment *(Delete the #)* this line `Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc`, then save the file and execute these commands `ssh-keygen -A` and `service ssh restart`.

If you did it well then you should be able to ssh without adding this `-oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` to the ssh command.

Comment: This is basically what the original answer says, except that it leaves the defaults alone and simply *adds* one kex mechanism.  Also, the 3des ciphers alone aren't needed - you simply need to only alter the KexAlgorithms - no need to alter the ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

```
nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

add these:

```
KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

exit

```
service ssh restart
```

then you can remote your hosts as usual:

```
ssh username@hostname
or
ssh -l username hostname
```

it works for me.. :)